# WordPress: user registration not working because of missing setting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I’ve encountered an issue where users are not able to register on our website. After some research and running WordPress in debug mode I’ve found out that this is the issue:

`WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO wp_users (user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, display_name, user_login) VALUES ('value', 'value', 'value', '', '2023-05-23 19:13:29', '', 'value', 'value') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Form_Handler::process_registration, wc_create_new_customer, wp_insert_user`

Please note; I have replaced some data with value because of privacy. After getting this error, I started investigating the database and found out that in the table wp_users there is no AUTO_INCREMENT setting at the row ID. So this is probably causing this issue. After some more research I also discovered this AUTO_INCREMENT has disappeared when the website was moved in the past (10-04-2022) because that was when the last user was created. The website has been moved on that date and probably made a mistake with not adding the AUTO_INCREMENT on the user ID.

When I tried to activate AUTO_INCREMENT for the row I got the following error:

`ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I hope someone here knows how this can be fixed.

Thanks!